# My input type slider value shows under the slider but I dont know why

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have html code which allows a user to select a percentage with an input type range.  This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="beneName">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="beneName" id="beneName" placeholder="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].beneName" required="">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="beneAddressLine1">Address Line 1</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="beneAddressLine1" id="beneAddressLine1" placeholder="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].beneAddressLine1" required="">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <label for="beneAddressLine2">Address Line 2</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="beneAddressLine2" id="beneAddressLine2" placeholder="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].beneAddressLine2" required="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <label for="beneAddressLine3">Address Line 3</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="beneAddressLine3" id="beneAddressLine3" placeholder="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].beneAddressLine3" required="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <label for="beneSSN">Social Security Number</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="beneSSN" id="beneSSN" placeholder="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].beneSSN" required="">
       </div>
  <div class="col-mid-6">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="benePercent" class="form-label">Percentage</label>
          <input type="range" name="benePercent" id="benePercent" class="percentAlign" value="@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].benePctInt" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
          <output class="percentAlign">@Model.BeneficiaryUpdateData[r].benePctInt</output>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css for percentAlign:

```
    .percentAlign {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

And this is what gets generated:

[image]

I dont understand why the percent value displays below the slider and not next to it.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

First edit:  A slight change suggested by Drexx_Dusan.  Now, the slider reaches to the end of the `<DIV>` but the `<OUTPUT>` is still displaying underneath the slider, not next to it.

[image]

Comment: post it as a snippet and give css code for the classes that you are using

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have col-mid-6 instead of col-md-6, in the div above last form group.

Comment: I made your suggested change.  Now, the slider reaches to the end of the <div> but the <output> is still displaying under.  I will edit the post to reflect this change.

Comment: I stripped down my code and have come to the conclusion that including https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css is what is causing the problem.  I have no idea why. I created a codepen here https://codepen.io/jonathn6/pen/qxMxBm.  When the bootstrap.min.css is not included, the slider shows with the <input> and <output> inline.  When the bootstrap.min.css is included, the <output> displays under the <input>.

Comment: @JonathanSmall that is indeed weird. I tried your code on my pc, just using bootstrap cdn and it works perfectly, have u tried adding `!important` to your css display? Also what version of bootstrap are you using? Try removing and adding it again. I saw the version, try using version 4 or 5, maybe it will help.